# cuda 8.0 appearing in apt-get autoremove list, 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, cuda

I installed the CUDA 8.0 toolkit on Ubuntu 16.04 successfully a few days ago.
Then suddenly today after running 'apt-get update', it started saying the cuda 8.0 toolkit is no longer needed.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
cuda-command-line-tools-8-0 cuda-core-8-0 cuda-cublas-8-0
cuda-cublas-dev-8-0 cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-cudart-dev-8-0 cuda-cufft-8-0
cuda-cufft-dev-8-0 cuda-curand-8-0 cuda-curand-dev-8-0 cuda-cusolver-8-0
cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0 cuda-cusparse-8-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0
cuda-documentation-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-8-0 cuda-license-8-0
cuda-misc-headers-8-0 cuda-npp-8-0 cuda-npp-dev-8-0 cuda-nvgraph-8-0
cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0
cuda-samples-8-0 cuda-toolkit-8-0 cuda-visual-tools-8-0 freeglut3
freeglut3-dev nvidia-modprobe
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now, i'm just afraid to do any apt-get upgrade or autoremove in case the whole installation would go away and all the config get messed up. What hould I do?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you installed CUDA. If you ran `sudo apt-get install <some-package-which-depends-on-CUDA>`, and that package was removed, then CUDA, an automatically installed package, becomes automatically removable. The simple fix is to mark the CUDA packages as manually installed:

```
sudo apt-mark manual cuda-\*
```